# wrong concat of panda series in date time pyplot error TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Timestamp', ,

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, time-series

I was running for forecasting, but due to pandas series append not working properly I got error
please ref code  : https://code.datasciencedojo.com/rebeccam/tutorials/blob/master/Time%20Series/py_time_series_example.py

```
hourly_sentiment_series = pd.read_csv('hourly_users_sentiment_subset.csv',
                                 index_col=0,
                                 parse_dates=True,
                                 squeeze=True ) #time series
```

hourly_users_sentiment_subset has 2- column as 1-datetime,2-users_sentiment_score

2)`hourly_sentiment_series.head(2)`

datetime

2019-02-06 00:00:00   -0.000745

2019-02-06 01:00:00   -0.099152

Name: users_sentiment_score, dtype: float64

3. now when trying to add `predicted_series_value` with no (datetime)

2019-02-06 22:00:00   -0.042334

2019-02-06 23:00:00   -0.038092

Name: users_sentiment_score, dtype: float64

4. `hourly_sentiment_full_predicted= hourly_sentiment_series.append(predicted_series_value)`
5. `pyplot.plot(hourly_sentiment_full_predicted, c='orange', label='predicted')`

TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Timestamp'

I feel error in append causing issue, Can some tell me how to add in proper format

Comment: It works fine with https://pastebin.com/cPw2x8yx on matplotlib 3.3.0. [preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9RjjZ.png).

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh  Thanks it was due to version issue, I was running on matplotlib-3.1.3, now working fine